# JAVA: SWT Text + MouseListener

Tags: java, swt, mouselistener, settext

Let me describe little bit whats my situation,
I have SWT `Text` in my Java SE SWT application: 
let say USER will write something (`String`) to the created `Text` while app running. I would like to introduce some `MouseListener` which would do exactly this:
When USER would click into `Text`object/widget, this `Text` would clear(`setText("");`) itselves(if there was previously written some String).

`MouseListener` has 3 methods: `mouseDown(...)`, `mouseUp(..)`, `mouseDoubleClick(...)` -> I should use only`mouseDown(...)` in this case - nothing more isnt nescesary.

In `mouseDown(..)` method I would need to call method of actual Text object reference : `"XY".setText("");` Text which was clicked-into by mouse. -> This I somehow could not obtain.

I would like to have it somehow like general `MouseListener onMouseClickText` which could be applied to any SWT `Text` I will use in my app.

Does anybody know how to do such `MouseListener` or better : how to obtain this reference to existing clicked SWT `Text`, inside `MouseListener`?

***here is example code:***

```
package sk.tokra.example;

//imports here
.
.
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
.
.

public class Application {

 //class fields
 Text text;
 private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);
 .
 .
 .

 // main 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  logger.debug("main(), Starting app!");
  try {
   Application window = new Application();
   window.open();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  logger.debug("main(), Exiting app!");
  return;
 }

 /**
  * Open the window.
  */
 public void open() {
  logger.debug("open()");
  Display display = Display.getDefault();
  createContents();
  shell.open();
  shell.layout();
  while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
   if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
   }
  }
 }

 /**
  * Create contents of the window.
  */
 protected void createContents() {
  text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
  text.addMouseListener(onMouseClickText);
  . 
  .
  .
 }

 //other stuff/methods/listener part
 private MouseListener onMouseClickText = new MouseListener() {
  @Override
  public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
   logger.debug("onMouseClickFind, mouseUp()");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
   logger.debug("onMouseClickFind, mouseDown()");
   // HERE I WOULD NEED to obtain refence of Text
   // then call .setText("");
  }

  @Override
  public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent arg0) {
   logger.debug("onMouseClickFind, mouseDoubleClick()");
  }
 };
}
```

Comment: :why do want to do it using mouse listener .You can do it in better way by using on Focus event of textfield .See javadocs for details.Its very easy this way.

Comment: Yes, but can it be done for general ? Do you know what it ment ? To have general Event/Listener for any SWT Text: to have only one declaration of Event or Listener whatever.. which could be added to any Text widget/object, without code duplicity. ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Naveen suggested it is much better to you use a focus listener because the same text widget can receive focus through numerous different ways (like tabbing on keyboard). You might want to handle that case as well.

In any case, whether you use a `FocusListener` or `MouseListener` on the `Text`, you can fetch the widget which actually caused the event. In case of the mouse listener you receive an instance of `MouseEvent` and you can use `MouseEvent#widget` to access the Text control. Your code would look something like below in the listener implementation:

```java
//other stuff/methods/listener part
private MouseListener onMouseClickText = new MouseListener() {
  @Override
  public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
    ((Text) arg0.widget).setText("");
  }
...
}
```

You may add the same listener instance to multiple `Text` widgets, it should work.